How do I only track one subteam's tasks on a Kanban Board?
I have a very real scenario ... right now. I have a lot of requirements in the queue and a dozen teams, each representing a different subsystem of the overall complex product, and any combo of these teams is needed, from 1 to 12, to contribute to resolving a given issue in one backlog full of Epics. The teams have their own tasks they need to track on their own Kanban boards. They already have a dashboard with team specific plots. I need a dashboard gadget that only shows their tasks on the Kanban Board. Filters for a dashboard are easy to code JQL for. But what do I do for the Kanban board? Thanks!

You say "JQL" but tagged azure-boards. So is this question for Jira or Azure?

Jira ...........

I think it is not clear if you want to have help on some software (Jira) or dealing with "real" physical kanban-boards. Maybe your question is better covered in a Jira forum or a dedicated stack exchange on software?
